# Selecting a Named Range Cell Location EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

Basically I want to select a specific cell that my named range is referencing and not returning the Value. I want to mimic the below, but been having errors with selecting the cell address.

```
Range("AU8").Select
```

What I have been trying which hasn't been working.

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("Root").Select
ThisWorkbook.Names("Root").Cells(1,1).Select
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "hasn't been working" is not really a useful description of what happens when you run your code.  When posting it always helps to include the exact error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.RefersToRange` property of the `Name` Object. Like so:

`ThisWorkbook.Names("Root").RefersToRange.Select`

But the `.Select` method will fail if the sheet is not active. A better method is `Application.Goto` like so:

`Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Names("Root").RefersToRange`

Side Note:
`.Select` is often a pointless and wasteful method that hinders the speed and accuracy of your macro scripts. Instead of relying on `.Select` and `Selection`, you can instead remove both, and directly reference the ranges that you want to interact with.

Comparison:

```vb
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection = "Input Text"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = "Input Text"
```

The last line does the same thing as the previous 4, but skips the steps of activating the workbook, sheet and range individually, which removes that screen jittering, and speeds up the execution of the script by massive amounts.